# Array from multiselect with Sumoselect library

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

Now I'm try to collect array for count my price from multi-select component. I use [Sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) and now I'm have push  1 item in array. But I'm want array with selected item data element.How did i make this?

https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/1a431069ffa40531e96b1375d553dd5a

Comment: can you create in jsfiddle?

Comment: Paste your code here so it will be better way to solve your issue.